# What is the origin of the word Gebühr?

Tags: etymology

What is the origin of the word Gebühr (fee)? I'm having trouble remembering it and am looking for help to break it down into its parts. Does the ge- prefix usually indicate something in particular? Are there other related words with -bühr in them?

Comment: A highwayman tells you: Give me your watch! Geb Uhr!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Gebühr* is the noun for the verb *gebühren*. This is defined by [dwds.de](http://dwds.de/wb/geb%C3%BChren) as follows (excerpt):

> **gebühren Vb**. "(nach Recht oder Verdienst) zustehen", (refl. und unpersönlich) "sich gehören, sich schicken", ahd. *giburien, giburren* "erheben, geschehen, hinzukommen, zuteil werden, zufallen" (um 800), mhd. *gebürn*

*gebühren* is still in use today in proverbs such as *Ehre, wem Ehre gebührt*. Also the adjective is used, for example in *das wurde gebührend gefeiert* (something was celebrated appropriately - in most cases this means excessively ;-)) or *seine Verdienste werden nicht gebührend gewürdigt*.

So by that definition, *Gebühr* is something that somebody deserves or that is righteously his. This can be used in the sense of a *fee*, but there's also the expression *über Gebühr [strapazieren/ausnutzen/etc]*, which means that something is done excessively, unduly. For example:

> Ich will Ihre Zeit nicht über Gebühr in Anspruch nehmen.
>   I don't want to encroach on your time.

The *ge-* in this case is not a prefix, so there's also no root *-bühren*.

Answer (score 7):

[Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Gebuehr) says the origin of *Gebühr* is:

> mittelhochdeutsch gebür(e), althochdeutsch giburi, eigentlich = was
>   einem zukommt, zufällt, zu gebühren

Translated to English:

> Middle High German: gebür(e), Old High German: giburi (actual meaning = what accords someone, devolve, appertains to someone

Thus, the "Ge-" in *Gebühr* is no prefix, but part of the root word.